# Unable to edit salesforce record using native android salesforce SDK

Tags: android, url, webview, salesforce

I am using android native **Salesforce SDK** to sync salesforce data in my android application. I am trying to open a URL to edit salesforce contacts using a native webview but loading the URL shows this message:

> 'To access this page, you have to log in to Salesforce'.

Entering valid credentials does not redirect anywhere else but reloads the login page with the above error message.

Here's the URL I am passing:

```
https://domain.visual.force.com/apex/GenericUpdate?isdtp=nv&id={record_id}&oauth_token={oAuthToken}&display=touch
```

Why am I not able to go to edit record page? Is it something to do with using a native webview not able to manage session? If so, how do I let my native webview to manage the session like for the salesforce login page?

Also, I was guided to use **frontdoor.jsp** (from hybrid mobile SDK) to login via native apps (Here's the link: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/1506) and the new URL is:

```
https://domain.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?&sid=&retURL=https://domain.visual.force.com/apex/GenericUpdate?isdtp=nv&id={record_id}&oauth_token={oAuthToken}&display=touch
```

Passing above gives me same error message. Does the `frontdoor.jsp` URL manage a session internally? If so, why doesn't it allow me to go to the edit page?

*Please note:* The above URLs are URLEncoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to solve this issue by setting web in oauthScope parameters array in bootconfig.xml of salesforce SDK like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="remoteAccessConsumerKey">key
</string>
    <string name="oauthRedirectURI">redirect url</string>
    <string-array name="oauthScopes">
        <item>web</item>
        <item>api</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add these remoteAccessConsumerKey and oauthRedirectURI value in Java code ? I want to change at runtime

Comment: I don't think so. I explored BuildConfig.java class and it doesn't show any setters, just have methods for reading the configurations from json or xml.